# Cómo calculo la cantidad de elementos y muestro luego solo los que esten por debajo del promedio

Tags: python, python-2.7

Un usuario le va indicar la siguiente información:

Una lista de nombres artículos y la cantidad de existencias de estos

La cantidad de elementos es variable.

Con estos datos, usted debe imprima un listado por pantalla, aplicando un filtrado, en el que se muestren solo aquellos artículos cuya cantidad sea menor al promedio de las cantidad introducidas.
Ejemplo:

Introduzca Item #1 y cantidad : Clavos 16
Introduzca Item #2 y cantidad : Tuercas 18
Introduzca Item #3 y cantidad : Jhovanny 20

El Promedio es = (16+18+20)/3 = 18

Los artículos con cantidad menor al promedio son: 
* Clavos con 16

Comment: Deberias intentar realizar algo y venir con dudas aqui solo pusiste tu problema de clases

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas como funciona el sitio. También revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: misma respuesta. la idea acá es ayudarte a mejorar tu código o hacerte ver donde te has equivocado, trata de hacer algo tu mismo y después, si tienes algún problema con tu código, pides ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, apenas ando conociendo el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Para introducir la información de un usuario a través de python, puedes utilizar el siguiente fragmento de código indicando los nombres de artículos y la cantidad.

**La lógica la debes desarrollar tu en mi respuesta solo te apoyo con sintaxis para que se te facilite desarrollar dicho problema.**

```
Item1= int(input("Escriba Item#1: "))
Cantidad= int(input("Escriba Cantidad: "))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me haz esclarecido un poco porque estaba haciéndolo de otra manera con listas y len pero solo me arrojaba los elementos. Gracias.

Comment: De nada, abajo la contestaron ya, deberías marcarla con palomita.

Comment: Disculpa, no se como hacerlo soy nueva.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printlista(lista,promedio):
    N = len(lista)
    for i in range(N):
        if (lista[i][1] <= promedio):
            print lista[i][0],lista[i][1]
    return

def main ():
    N = int(raw_input("Cantidad de articulos? "))
    if (N > 0):
        L = []
        S = 0
        P = 0.0
        for i in range(N):
            A,c = raw_input("Articulo y cantidad: ").split()
            C = int(c)
            #A = str(raw_input("Articulo? "))
            #C = int(raw_input("Cantidad? "))
            S = S + C
            L. append([A,C])
        P = S / N
        printlista(L,P)
    return


main()
```

Lo resolví con este código pero se supone que al ingresar cantidad de articulos 3 y agregar clavos 16, tuercas 18 y jhonny 20 solo debería aparecerme 16 porque esta debajo del promedio pero tambien me aparece tuercas 18.

Comment: Ya lo resolví disculpen, no me había percatado que tenía <= XD

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que ya tienes una lista con los artículos puedes resolverlo de dos formas:

1. Usando numpy

   ```
   import numpy as np

   # Convierte la lista a un array de numpy
   items = np.array([16, 18, 20])
   # Aplica una condición que filtra solo los valores menores al promedio
   condition = items < items.mean()
   items[condition]
   ```
2. Usando solo python

   ```
   items = [16, 18, 20]
   # Hallamos la media
   mean = sum(items)/len(items)
   # Filtramos la lista y convertimos el resultado en una lista.
   list( filter(lambda x: x < mean, items) )
   ```

Ya que eres nueva en python, te recomiendo estas opciones cuya principal ventaja es que no usan bucles FOR y que puedas ver la potencia en las librerias esenciales como numpy.